# How can I start this program in prolog?

Tags: prolog, expert-system

The source is here
([source](http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/code/native/birds.nkb))

I though was with bird(X). But I think I need something more.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes `bird(X)`, it's working with swi-prolog with some help     https://github.com/Anniepoo/amziexpertsystemsinprolog/blob/master/nativeshell.pl

Comment: @ömeryılmaz yeah the thing after give the X or any bird name like laysan_albatross thiss error ERROR: nostrils/1: Undefined procedure: ask/2 will show

Comment: yes, those procedures are for amzi i guess, i merged this file with the one above and when i consult the file it starts a shell, i `quit` the shell and type `bird(X)`, it starts to ask questions. it's possible to copy only related procedures too; `ask`, `askmenu` etc...

Comment: @ömeryılmaz Sorry but how did you merge the files?

Comment: @ömeryılmaz I make a file with name birds.nkb with the code in the link of the source I show in my question this(http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/code/native/birds.nkb) then I make another file with code in the link you gave me the "nativeshell.pl" then I start the program, it starts a shell then I put load then ask for the file birds.nkb i put the name 'birds.nkb'. but the prolog show me a error telling me the files doesn't exist even if I have both files in the same directory

Comment: Just copy and paste to the end of the file above. File name extension for swi prolog is `.pl`, later use `consult` command inside prolog http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1 to load file.  If you copied whole file it's starting a shell, type `quit.`. Later you can use the program by typing `bird(X).`

Comment: @ömeryılmaz Thank you so much i could reproduce the example!